# Prevent GridView ActionColumn icons from wrapping globally

Tags: php, gridview, yii2

I tried to find the answer, but couldn't and wonder why it is designed like this:

My action columns icons do wrap one below the other.

I have to add this line of code in every `GridView` to show icons on one line:

```
[
    'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
    'contentOptions' => ['width' => '80px;'],
],
```

Is there any better method to show the action icon on one line globally?

Comment: You should use `white-space` instead of `width`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should create file "container.php" in config folder. And put this code

```
<?php
\Yii::$container->set('yii\grid\ActionColumn', [
        'contentOptions' => ['width' => '80px;'],
]);
```

Then, You should include this file in your "web/index.php". Like that

```
<?php

// comment out the following two lines when deployed to production
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);
defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'dev');

require(__DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php');
require(__DIR__ . '/../vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php');

$config = require(__DIR__ . '/../config/web.php');

require(__DIR__ . '/../config/container.php');

(new yii\web\Application($config))->run();
```

It is work like that - https://yadi.sk/i/kpgus0eAeeHDw

Comment: Could also just put that code in the index.php instead of its own file

Answer (score 2):

Building on top of [@vitalik_74's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28487459/prevent-gridview-actioncolumn-icons-from-wrapping-globally#answer-28492835), I added the nowrap style for that column instead of the width.

```
\Yii::$container->set('yii\grid\ActionColumn', [
        'contentOptions' => ['style' => ['white-space' => 'nowrap']],
]);
```